# Group created_at by cweek in rails where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, activerecord

Im trying to analyse some data on a historical week by week basis.

Currently using

```
Model.where(:created_at => 3.weeks.ago..2.weeks.ago)
Model.where(:created_at => 2.weeks.ago..1.week.ago)
..etc
```

I want to analyse by cweek.

Is there a way to do that sensibly? 
i.e.

```
Model.where(:created_at.cweek => Date.Now.cweek)
```

I'm sure there's a very simple way to do this.

Comment: Across all years or within a given year?

Comment: Happy with just the general way to do it. Let's assume a given year for now. Pretty comfortable that I can work out the year overlap if I can work out how to write the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find all records within a given year and week you could use:

```
week_range = Date.commercial(2014, 35).to_time.all_week
Model.where(created_at: week_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

application_helper.rb

```
def weeks_ago_range(number)
  number.weeks.ago.all_week
end
```

Then

```
Model.where(:created_at => weeks_ago_range(1)).count
```

I think the answer above might have more general use and actually answers my original question better, but with this I don't even need to know the cweek.

Comment: You can also use `number.weeks.ago.all_week`, it returns the same range